# Count per category in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have what seems to be a simple issue, but of course it never is.

I have data that looks like this (I'm displaying pipe-delimited):

```
Identifier | Roll Up | Sequence

1234       | 4567    | 1

1234       | 4567    | 2

1235       | 4567    | 1

1235       | 4567    | 2

1236       | 6789    | 1

1237       | 6789    | 1
```

So, the Identifier is the 'version' of the Roll Up field, and each Roll Up field has sequences.

What I need to do is have an extra column that counts the 'version' of the Roll Up, as such:

```
Version |Identifier | Roll Up | Sequence

1       |1234       | 4567    | 1

1       |1234       | 4567    | 2

2       |1235       | 4567    | 1

2       |1235       | 4567    | 2

1       |1236       | 6789    | 1

2       |1237       | 6789    | 1
```

I thought it would be a simple ***count each Identifier per Roll Up*** but I couldn't get it to correctly do that with `COUNT()` or `ROW_NUMBER().`

Would anyone have a solution for that derived column?

Thanks much,
Turner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a column to your simple query like this:

```
row_number() over (partition by Identifier, Roll_Up order by Identifier, Roll_Up)
```

I think would be the script producing the final result:

```
SELECT  t0.*, count1
FROM  Test AS t0 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Identifier1, ROLLUP1,
     Row_Number() Over
   (Partition BY Identifier1, Rollup1
    ORDER BY Identifier1, RollUp1) AS count1
   FROM Test
   ) AS t1
  ON t0.Identifier1 = t1.Identifier1
  AND t0.ROLLUP1 = t1.ROLLUP1
```

Comment: This replicated what the Sequence field is showing - it is giving me an increment per Identifier - Roll Up combination.  I need an increment per Identifier within each Roll Up.

Comment: @Turner Take a look at this page which Laurence created, I think it produces the right result.

Comment: Thanks!  Those solutions work well.

I also found what was tripping up the aggregate - the Sequence number.

If I do 
row_number() over (partition by Identifier, Sequence order by Identifier, Roll_Up) as Version

I get the correct result as well when selecting all of the fields.

Thanks again!